# Falha ao carregar CSS

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa tarde.

A seguinte aplicação: http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/ em codeigniter não carrega o CSS.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sitemodelo/hqfree/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *base_url* deve ter a URL base para os arquivos serem carregados. Quando você informa "http://23.88.113.70/" (como está no site), o navegador vai tentar carregar os arquivos "http://23.88.113.70/js/funcoes.js" ao invés de "http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/js/funcoes.js"

A sua *base_url* **deve** ser http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/

Comment: Boa tarde. Coloquei conforme informado mas sem sucesso: $config['base_url'] = 'http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/';

Comment: @MHPA Se possível atualiza no site para que eu possa ver o resultado. Você também pode remover o `$config['base_url']`.

Comment: Esta atualizado no site. vi nos comandos que ele da falha ao carregar vários arquivos.

Comment: É uma VPS na budgetVM ainda falta configurar um dominio para substituir o ip, mas primeiro gostaria de testar a aplicação.

Comment: Faz o seguinte. Adicione `<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />` ou então `<base href="https://url-completa-do-site" />` no seu arquivo onde está o `header`

Comment: Adicionei no meu home-page.php esta no site, mas não apareceu nada

Comment: <base href="http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/" />
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
<h1>teste</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

Comment: @MHPA Ele deve ficar no `header`, se possível depois que abrir a tag. Ex: <html><header><base href="...." /> todo o resto do código </header></html> e remova o $config['base_url']

Comment: Adicionei:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="http://23.88.113.70/public_html/sitemodelo/hqfree/" />
    <base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
    <title>
        <?php echo $this->titleView;?>
    </title>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73225/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-mhpa).

Comment: desculpa esqueci de remover a outra tag, agora esta removido.